# Testing a protected api call, mocha, supertest, node js, passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js, supertest

I have a protected api call with passport as middleware:

```
  server.get('/api/pipes', auth, api.pipes);
```

The auth method returns a 401 if the user is no authorized.

I have this test to see if the user is loggedin:

```
  var postValidLoginCredentials = function(){
    return request(url).post('/api/login')
      .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
      .field('email', 'john.smith@example.com')
      .field('password', 'example')
  };

//This pass passes
it('should return 200 OK when a user enters a valid user and pass', function(done){
  postValidLoginCredentials()
  .end(function(err, res){
    res.should.have.status('200');
    done();
  });
});
```

This is my test for my protected api call:

```
it('should return 200 OK on GET /api/pipes when user is loggedin', function (done) {
      postValidLoginCredentials()
        .end(function(err, res){
          request(url)
            .get('/api/pipes')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect(200, done);
        })
    });
```

I first post my login. In the login callback I then call my protected api call. It should be 200 but I get 401. The feature works in my client, so it's something wrong in my test.

I also tried to but my postValidLoginCredentials in a function, but it didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you have a chance to check my suggestion below?

Comment: Thx for your answear. I found a solution before you posted. I used the  set cookie in my login. Then I uset "get" cookie in my protected path call. I used the lower level superagent to do this. So I'm not sure if your solution works.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment, but you shouldn't set the cookie yourself, since passport will do it for you. Or did you only modify your test and I got it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you're using the "local" login strategy, and maintain session with cookies.

After a user is logged in, you need a way to identify the logged in user that's making the authenticated request. When using a session ID in a cookie, you could do it like this:

```
it('should return 200 OK on GET /api/pipes when user is loggedin', function (done) {
      postValidLoginCredentials()
        .end(function(err, res){
          request(url)
            .get('/api/pipes')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .set('Cookie', res.headers['set-cookie'])
            .expect(200, done);
        })
    });
```

However, that's just a workaround and you should use supertest's agent feature instead. You can read about it in the [README](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) (the example is precisely about cookie storage), or read a bunch of [tests using it](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/master/test/node/agency.js) in the supertest repo.